# Mouse cursor moves and clicks by itself Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, wacom

My mouse cursor seems to sometimes decide to randomly click - left and right - and move around. This is not caused by the mouse itself, as it only happens on Ubuntu (I'm using dual boot with Windows 10) and regardless of mouse used (it also doesn't happen when that mouse is plugged into a different Ubuntu 18.04 computer)
.
The only notable thing I can think of is that I'm using an ancient Wacom Bamboo Pen and Fun tablet that doesn't work on Windows anymore, but somehow still works on Ubuntu. However, the issue  happens even when the tablet isn't plugged in, so perhaps it's not that.

Once the issue starts happening (which might take couple hours or 10 minutes, it seems completely random), there is no other way to stop it aside from rebooting, which is incredibly annoying.

xinput output with tablet off:

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MEDION MEDION MD86825 USB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MEDION MEDION MD86825 USB Gaming Keyboard Mouse   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HP Virtual Keyboard                       id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ GeneralPlus USB Audio Device              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MEDION MEDION MD86825 USB Gaming Keyboard id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MEDION MEDION MD86825 USB Gaming Keyboard System Control  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Virtual Keyboard                       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MEDION MEDION MD86825 USB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

xinput output with tablet plugged in, in case that's relevant:

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MEDION MEDION MD86825 USB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MEDION MEDION MD86825 USB Gaming Keyboard Mouse   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HP Virtual Keyboard                       id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom BambooPT 2FG 4x5 Pen stylus         id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom BambooPT 2FG 4x5 Pen eraser         id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom BambooPT 2FG 4x5 Pad pad            id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom BambooPT 2FG 4x5 Finger touch       id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ GeneralPlus USB Audio Device              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MEDION MEDION MD86825 USB Gaming Keyboard id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MEDION MEDION MD86825 USB Gaming Keyboard System Control  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Virtual Keyboard                       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MEDION MEDION MD86825 USB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**EDIT:** I thought the fact that my keyboard was named as a pointer device was suspicious, so I tried using `xinput --disable` to disable both of these devices. However, it didn't work, and issues resumed after a couple hours.

**EDIT 2:** I forgot to mention, but whenever the issues occur, what ALSO occurs is that sound from my speakers gets all glitchy. I'm using an USB sound card plugged into a USB hub, since my computer doesn't have an internal sound card. My mouse is also plugged into very same USB hub. (Mind you, issues still only happen on Ubuntu) I switched mouse to a regular USB port and we'll see if issues will persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days, I'm certain - the issue was my cheap USB hub. I have no idea why it only acted up on Ubuntu, but alas. I guess cheap devices like that aren't really tested on Linux, I'm assuming.

Switching mouse to a regular USB port made everything work perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks you so much for this!  Power cycling my USB hub resolved this for me.